# How to use case when in where conditon tsql?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Following is the part of a stored procedure:-

```
@ID int
@Col1 int
@Col2 int

Select * 
from Table_01 t1
JOIN table_02 t2 on t1.col = t2.col
where 
  1 = case when @Col1 = 0 then 1 else (case when t2.Col1 = @Col1 then 1 else 0 end) end
  AND 1 = case when @Col2 = 0 then 1 else (case when t2.Col2 = @Col2 then 1 else 0 end) end
  AND 1 = case when @ID = 0 then 1 else (case when t2.ID = @ID then 1 else 0 end) end
```

Currently

- if `@ID = 0` then it ignores the condition
- if @ID has value then it returns results based on the criteria satisfaction

I need to add another condition there :-

`if @ID = -1` then should not return any result (coz there is no match) 
but it should act like `@ID = 0` (ignore to add expresssion)

Am I clear? :(

Comment: Should this last condition trump the other two?

Comment: This is completely unsargable even with `option (recompile)` in SQL Server 2005 as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select ...
From Table_01 As t1
    Join table_02 As t2 
        On t1.col = t2.col
Where Case 
        When @ID = 0 Then 1 
        When t2.ID = @ID Then 1 
        When @ID = -1 Then 0
        Else 0 
        End = 1
```

If this last condition should trump the other two, then you need to change the order:

```
Select ...
From Table_01 As t1
    Join table_02 As t2 
        On t1.col = t2.col
Where Case 
        When @ID = -1 Then 0
        When @ID = 0 Then 1 
        When @ID = t2.ID Then 1 
        Else 0 
        End = 1
```

Of course another way which may perform better (assuming `@ID = -1` trumps):

```
Select ...
From Table_01 As t1
    Join table_02 As t2 
        On t1.col = t2.col
Where @ID != -1 
    And ( @ID = 0 Or @ID = t2.ID )
```

**Update based on edit of OP**

It sounds like you are trying to do something like the following:

```
Select ...
From Table_01 As t1
    Join table_02 As t2 
        On t1.col = t2.col
Where @ID != -1
    And ( @Col1 = 0 Or @Col1 = t2.Col1 )
    And ( @Col2 = 0 Or @Col2 = t2.Col2 )
    And ( @ID = 0 Or @ID = t2.ID )
```

Comment: Thanks.. a little problem... see my edited question. I have more than one AND condtion there.. IF @ID = -1 then I don't what that condition should be utlimately like this : where t2.Col1 = 5 and t2.Col2 = 1 and t2.ID = -1 (coz -1 has no match)

Comment: @Jango - I've updated my answer. It sounds like you simply need a series of AND statements instead of using Case expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to write it so it is clearer:

```
WHERE @ID IN (0, t2.ID) AND @ID <> -1
```

or

```
WHERE (@ID = 0 OR t2.ID = @ID) AND @ID <> -1
```

If t2.ID can not be -1 then you don't need that part.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you simply want `@ID = -1` to have the same effect as `@ID = 0`. In that case here is how your query might look like:

```
Select * 
FROM Table_01 t1
  JOIN table_02 t2 on t1.col = t2.col
WHERE @Col1 IN (0, t2.Col1)
  AND @Col2 IN (0, t2.Col2)
  AND @ID IN (-1, 0, t2.ID)
```